# Creating a 2D NumPy array from a binaryfile where the total length is unkown

Tags: python, numpy, file, text-files, binaryfiles

I'm having trouble with creating a NumPy array from a binary file.

The binary file is made up by many  *c_int32*  containing samples from multiple microphones. The data is written the the file in order starting with:

frequency + sampleCounter + mic*1 +* mic*2 +* mic*3 +* mic4

I sample data for about 2 seconds, so I have a quite large binary file.

What I want to do is to create a NumPy array from the binary file with 6 columns.

lLke this:

frequency, sampleCounter, mic*1, mic2, mic3*, mic4
frequency, sampleCounter, mic*1, mic2, mic3*, mic4
frequency, sampleCounter, mic*1, mic2, mic3*, mic4
frequency, sampleCounter, mic*1, mic2, mic3*, mic4
frequency, sampleCounter, mic*1, mic2, mic3*, mic4
frequency, sampleCounter, mic*1, mic2, mic3*, mic4
frequency, sampleCounter, mic*1, mic2, mic3*, mic4

The problem is that the number of rows is unknown. Before I used a binary file, I stored the data in a textfile. Then I could read the file and create the NumPy array.

So the problem now is that I cant use a separator ',' which created a new row in the matrix.

Any ideas of a smart solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

You can read the complete file with [`fromfile`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fromfile.html):

```
data = numpy.fromfile(filename, dtype=numpy.int32)
```

This should give you n*6 values. Then just reshape the array:

```
data = data.reshape(-1, 6)
```